# TYPO3 Dynamic Localized Label in TypoScript

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x

In this example, `duration` is a database table field that stores the duration in integer form while `duration_type` is a field that holds an integer ranging from `0-3`. `0` represents seconds, `1` represents minutes, `2` represents hours. Labels are stored in EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf.

This works.

```
1 = TEXT
1 {
    field = duration
    stdWrap.dataWrap = {LLL:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:duration.1}: |
    stdWrap.required = 1
}
```

However, if try getting a dynamic label, it fails.

```
1 = TEXT
1 {
    field = duration
    stdWrap.dataWrap = {LLL:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:duration.{field:duration_type}}: |
    stdWrap.required = 1
}
```

So the desired outcome is something like seconds: 25.

How can I get the labels dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you have not told TYPO3 to replace the inner data.
I would suggest:

```
1 = TEXT
1 {
    field = duration
    stdWrap {
        dataWrap = {LLL:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:duration.{field:duration_type}}: |
        dataWrap.insertData = 1
        required = 1
    }
}
```